# Pagination with 3x3 in each page

Tags: php, pagination

Having problem with doing pagination with a layout of 3x3 
This is my while loop , tried out several pagination but too complicated

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $picture = $row['picture'];

    $rowPic = "<td><a href='dologinuser.php?id=$id'>";
    $rowPic .= "<img width='200px' height='133px' src='images/$picture' />";
    $rowPic .= "</a><br/>";
    $rowPic .= "<strong>$name</strong>";

    echo $rowPic;

    $split++;   
    if ($split%3==0){
     echo '</tr><tr>';
```

Comment: i have no idea in pagination , all too complex :/

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this? I believe it is more readable this way.

```
<?php
// Grouping the code into table-like array
$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $table[$count / 3][$count % 3] =  $row;
    $count++;
}

// Constructing HTML code
$html  = "<table>";
foreach($table as $row) {
    $html .= "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $col) {
        $id = $col['id'];
        $html .= "<td>" . "whatever you want to put" . "</td>";
    }
    $html .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= "</table>";
?>
```